# Overriding static generic method for type in C#

Tags: c#, generics, struct, static-methods, overriding

I am trying to write a generic method for the color conversion (Bgr -> Gray). The idea is to have some type specific conversions (e.g. for byte), and the fallback (default) conversion for other types.
The conversion methods are defined in Bgr where T can be byte, int, double, etc.

```
public struct Bgr<T>
  where T : struct
{
    public T B;
    public T G;
    public T R;

    public unsafe static void Convert(ref Bgr<byte> bgr, ref Gray<byte> gray)
    {
        //should be executed if T is byte...
    }

    public unsafe static void Convert(ref Bgr<T> bgr, ref Gray<T> gray)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

The converter class contains "ConvertBgrToGray" method which calls "Convert" method. The idea that the "Convert" for Bgr is called if the TSrcDepth is byte, but instead a default generic "Convert" is called which throws NotSupportedException.

```
public static class BgrGrayConverter
{
    public static void ConvertBgrToGray<TSrcDepth, TDstDepth>(Bgr<TSrcDepth>[,] source, Gray<TDstDepth>[,] dest)
        where TSrcDepth: struct
        where TDstDepth: struct
    {
       ...
       Gray<TSrcDepth> dstVal = default(Gray<TSrcDepth>);
       Bgr<TSrcDepth>.Convert(ref source[j, i], ref dstVal);
       ...
    }
}
```

How can I write this in an appropriate way so the default Convert method is called only if the specific type "overrride" is not found ? (Bgr must be a struct).

Or how to rewrite this in the "prettiest way" so that works ?

Comment: It will only use the `Convert` that accepts `Bgr<byte>` if it can determine that at compile time.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2008/04/14/gotcha-generic-overload-resolution-when-called-generically.aspx

Comment: @JohnKoerner Thank you.  How to rewrite this in the "prettiest way" so that works  ?